# Use Covariance Matrix to Convert Ellipsoid to Sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, covariance, spheres, ellipsoids

If I have an unbiased ellipsoid with a known covariance, is there a way I can use that covariance matrix to transform all known points on the given ellipsoid to trace a sphere instead?

Comment: Can you add equations to your question to clarify what you mean by unbiased ellipsoid ?

Comment: @HosamH, I simply mean the origin of the ellipsoid is (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Okay.  Can you add to your question some details of what you have tried.  This is one way to add context to your question, which is considered crucial in this website.  Otherwise you'll see that your question will receive close votes.

Comment: @HosamH, I'm not really sure how the context will help, but I'm trying to find an easy was to calibrate 3-axis magnetometer data. I can take out sensor bias easy, but fitting the ellipsoid data to a sphere is more challenging.

Comment: An ellipsoid doesn't have a covariance -- can you clarify this? Is this is a level set of a multivariate gaussian?

Comment: Do you mean a uniform distribution over an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a sphere you want all of the eigenvalues to be made equal. Left-multiply your datapoints (vectors) by $PDP^{-1}$, where $P$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of your covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose $k$th diagonal entry is equal to the required rescaling factor for the eigenvalue associated with $k$th column of $P$. That is:

$$\vec{v}_\text{new} = PDP^{-1}\vec{v}$$

and
$$ D = k\Lambda^{-1}$$
$k$ is your desired *universal* eigenvalue and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal eigenvalue matrix associated with $P$.

---

Equation of canonical $n$-dimensional hyperellipsoid:

$$\sum \frac{x_i^2}{\alpha_i^2}=1$$

Volume of $n$-dimensional hyperellipsoid:

$$V=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\prod_j\alpha_j$$

For a uniform distribution over the hyperellipsoid, the marginal distribution over R.V. $X_i$:

$$\begin{align}f_{X_i}(x_i) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_{i-1} dx_{i+1} \cdots dx_n\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}\prod_j\alpha_j }dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_{i-1} dx_{i+1} \cdots dx_n\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}\prod_j\alpha_j }\frac{(\alpha_i^2-x_i^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)\alpha_i^{n-1}}\prod_{j\neq i}\alpha_j,\text{ ($(n-1)$-dimensional hyperellipsoid volume at $x_i$)}\\ 
&= \frac{(\alpha_i^2-x_i^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\alpha_i^{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}
\end{align}$$

Variance of the marginal distribution over $X_i$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\alpha_i}^{\alpha_i}  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\alpha_i^{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} x_i^2(\alpha_i^2-x_i^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} dx_i
&= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\alpha_i^{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \frac{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}} {\alpha_i}^{n + 2} \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + 2\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right){\alpha_i}^{ 2}}{2 \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + 2\right)} \\
&= \frac{2{\alpha_i}^{ 2}}{2 (n+2)}\\
&= \frac{\alpha_i^2}{n+2}
\end{align}\\
$$

Therefore the $i$th semiaxis has length:

$$\alpha_i=\sigma_i\sqrt{n+2}$$

where $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation in the $i$th (orthogonal) direction.

So by multiplying the square root of the $i$th eigenvalue of the $n\times n$ covariance matrix by $\sqrt{n+2}$ you get an approximation of the $i$th semi-axis length.